# CAN Communication

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, can-bus

How can I implement CAN communication in c# windows application. I have to create an application that communicate to the device. In earlier project I used serial port. What will be the major difference between these two.. Am new to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a CAN controller. I would recommend the PCAN USB from PEAK Systems.
2. Install the drivers
3. Download the PCAN API from PEAK System web page. (contains C# wrappers)
4. Use the API in your application to send and receive CAN frames